# How do i add a link to this animated button

Tags: javascript, html

Essentially i found this button that i wanted to add to my wixsite that links to a store. I have gotten the button animation to work and this button exists as a html element on wix. But all the button does currently is do the animation and dosent link. Could someone edit this code so after the animation plays the user will be redirected to a certain link.

I've tried looking up link code and inserting it in logical places to determine where it might work but obviously i dident find anything. And even if it did it likely would have redirected before the animation finished.

Here is the code without any of my attempts to try and fix this problem.

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

Math.randMinMax = function (min, max, round) {
    var val = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));

    if (round) val = Math.round(val);

    return val;
};
Math.TO_RAD = Math.PI / 180;
Math.getAngle = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    var dx = x1 - x2,
        dy = y1 - y2;

    return Math.atan2(dy, dx);
};
Math.getDistance = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    var xs = x2 - x1,
        ys = y2 - y1;

    xs *= xs;
    ys *= ys;

    return Math.sqrt(xs + ys);
};

var FX = {};

(function () {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        lastUpdate = new Date(),
        mouseUpdate = new Date(),
        lastMouse = [],
        width, height;

    FX.particles = [];

    setFullscreen();
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mousedown', buttonEffect);

    function buttonEffect() {

        var button = document.getElementById('button'),
            height = button.offsetHeight,
            left = button.offsetLeft,
            top = button.offsetTop,
            width = button.offsetWidth,
            x, y, degree;

        for (var i = 0; i < 40; i = i + 1) {

            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {

                y = Math.randMinMax(top, top + height);

                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    x = left;
                    degree = Math.randMinMax(-45, 45);
                } else {
                    x = left + width;
                    degree = Math.randMinMax(135, 225);
                }

            } else {

                x = Math.randMinMax(left, left + width);

                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    y = top;
                    degree = Math.randMinMax(45, 135);
                } else {
                    y = top + height;
                    degree = Math.randMinMax(-135, -45);
                }

            }
            createParticle({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                degree: degree,
                speed: Math.randMinMax(100, 150),
                vs: Math.randMinMax(-4, -1)
            });
        }
    }
    window.setTimeout(buttonEffect, 100);

    loop();

    window.addEventListener('resize', setFullscreen);

    function createParticle(args) {

        var options = {
            x: width / 2,
            y: height / 2,
            color: 'hsla(' + Math.randMinMax(160, 290) + ', 100%, 50%, ' + (Math.random().toFixed(2)) + ')',
            degree: Math.randMinMax(0, 360),
            speed: Math.randMinMax(300, 350),
            vd: Math.randMinMax(-90, 90),
            vs: Math.randMinMax(-8, -5)
        };

        for (key in args) {
            options[key] = args[key];
        }

        FX.particles.push(options);
    }

    function loop() {

        var thisUpdate = new Date(),
            delta = (lastUpdate - thisUpdate) / 1000,
            amount = FX.particles.length,
            size = 2,
            i = 0,
            p;

        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(15,15,15,0.25)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        ctx.globalCompositeStyle = 'lighter';

        for (; i < amount; i = i + 1) {

            p = FX.particles[i];

            p.degree += (p.vd * delta);
            p.speed += (p.vs);// * delta);
            if (p.speed < 0) continue;

            p.x += Math.cos(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);
            p.y += Math.sin(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);

            ctx.save();

            ctx.translate(p.x, p.y);
            ctx.rotate(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD);

            ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
            ctx.fillRect(-size, -size, size * 2, size * 2);

            ctx.restore();
        }

        lastUpdate = thisUpdate;

        requestAnimFrame(loop);
    }

    function setFullscreen() {
        width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    };
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#myCanvas {
    display: block;
}

#button {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    background: hsla(260, 100%, 50%, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0 !important;
    animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
    transition: background 0.4s, border 0.2s, margin 0.2s;
}

    #button:hover {
        background: hsla(220, 100%, 60%, 1);
        margin-top: -1px;
        animation: none;
    }

    #button:active {
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    100% {
        margin-top: 6px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button">Donate</button>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

So again the expected result is to play the animation for the button then redirect to another page and the current result is the button simply playing the animation when clicked. If anyone could please write this code it would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an activity when click on button. For example:

```html
<button id="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';">Donate</button>
```

Demo:

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

Math.randMinMax = function (min, max, round) {
    var val = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));

    if (round) val = Math.round(val);

    return val;
};
Math.TO_RAD = Math.PI / 180;
Math.getAngle = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    var dx = x1 - x2,
        dy = y1 - y2;

    return Math.atan2(dy, dx);
};
Math.getDistance = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    var xs = x2 - x1,
        ys = y2 - y1;

    xs *= xs;
    ys *= ys;

    return Math.sqrt(xs + ys);
};

var FX = {};

(function () {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        lastUpdate = new Date(),
        mouseUpdate = new Date(),
        lastMouse = [],
        width, height;

    FX.particles = [];

    setFullscreen();
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mousedown', buttonEffect);

    function buttonEffect() {

        var button = document.getElementById('button'),
            height = button.offsetHeight,
            left = button.offsetLeft,
            top = button.offsetTop,
            width = button.offsetWidth,
            x, y, degree;

        for (var i = 0; i < 40; i = i + 1) {

            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {

                y = Math.randMinMax(top, top + height);

                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    x = left;
                    degree = Math.randMinMax(-45, 45);
                } else {
                    x = left + width;
                    degree = Math.randMinMax(135, 225);
                }

            } else {

                x = Math.randMinMax(left, left + width);

                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    y = top;
                    degree = Math.randMinMax(45, 135);
                } else {
                    y = top + height;
                    degree = Math.randMinMax(-135, -45);
                }

            }
            createParticle({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                degree: degree,
                speed: Math.randMinMax(100, 150),
                vs: Math.randMinMax(-4, -1)
            });
        }
    }
    window.setTimeout(buttonEffect, 100);

    loop();

    window.addEventListener('resize', setFullscreen);

    function createParticle(args) {

        var options = {
            x: width / 2,
            y: height / 2,
            color: 'hsla(' + Math.randMinMax(160, 290) + ', 100%, 50%, ' + (Math.random().toFixed(2)) + ')',
            degree: Math.randMinMax(0, 360),
            speed: Math.randMinMax(300, 350),
            vd: Math.randMinMax(-90, 90),
            vs: Math.randMinMax(-8, -5)
        };

        for (key in args) {
            options[key] = args[key];
        }

        FX.particles.push(options);
    }

    function loop() {

        var thisUpdate = new Date(),
            delta = (lastUpdate - thisUpdate) / 1000,
            amount = FX.particles.length,
            size = 2,
            i = 0,
            p;

        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(15,15,15,0.25)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        ctx.globalCompositeStyle = 'lighter';

        for (; i < amount; i = i + 1) {

            p = FX.particles[i];

            p.degree += (p.vd * delta);
            p.speed += (p.vs);// * delta);
            if (p.speed < 0) continue;

            p.x += Math.cos(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);
            p.y += Math.sin(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);

            ctx.save();

            ctx.translate(p.x, p.y);
            ctx.rotate(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD);

            ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
            ctx.fillRect(-size, -size, size * 2, size * 2);

            ctx.restore();
        }

        lastUpdate = thisUpdate;

        requestAnimFrame(loop);
    }

    function setFullscreen() {
        width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    };
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#myCanvas {
    display: block;
}

#button {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    background: hsla(260, 100%, 50%, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0 !important;
    animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
    transition: background 0.4s, border 0.2s, margin 0.2s;
}

    #button:hover {
        background: hsla(220, 100%, 60%, 1);
        margin-top: -1px;
        animation: none;
    }

    #button:active {
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    100% {
        margin-top: 6px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';">Donate</button>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so this works but as i was describing earlier this is simply a wix html element wich means it is code that exists in a box on the screen. Because of this when i run it, it simply opens the link within the element box so what do i have to do to make it refresh the entire page to that link.

Comment: You can change your `#button` tag to `<a>`, but the inner text will be left aligned, not center aligned.

Comment: sorry i dont think you know what i meant

Comment: this is the problem

Comment: You can change the activity in the `onclick`, maybe a function to load a frame.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your button to a href link. You may have to add some extra styling to the id class, but this should work.

```
<a id="button" href="https://www.linktosite.com">Link Button</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this on the button html tag `onclick="location.href='http://www.link.com'"`